# When do Leibniz-like rules lead to unique linear operators

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials, recursion

**Background**

Usually one defines differentiation in terms of limits, and then shows that differentiation satisfies the [Leibniz (product) rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule), 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f \cdot g) = f\frac{dg}{dx} + g \frac{df}{dx},$$ 
as a consequence.

However, in [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44774/do-these-properties-characterize-differentiation) I was surprised to find that one can go the other way around and use the Leibniz rule to define the derivative in a more algebraic/axiomatic manner. In particular, there exists a unique linear operator $L: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying the following three properties:

1. $L(1) = 0$
2. $L(x) = 1$
3. $L(f \cdot g) = f \cdot L(g) + g \cdot L(f),$

and so we can use these properties as the definition of the derivative operator instead.

**Question**

This naturally leads to the following question: if we replace the Leibniz rule with some different polynomial of the relevant quantities,
$$L(f \cdot g) = \text{polynomial}\left(f,g,L(f),L(g)\right),$$
for example,
$$L(f \cdot g) = g^3 \cdot L(f) \cdot L(g)^2 + f^2 \cdot g,$$

then under what conditions do the analogous three properties,

1. $L(1) = 0$
2. $L(x) = 1$
3. $L(f \cdot g) = \text{polynomial}\left(f,g,L(f),L(g)\right),$

also lead to a unique linear operator?

If so, are there specific examples of polynomials that lead to familiar linear operators (other than the derivative)?

**Works on polynomials?**

So far my thinking is as follows: given these three rules, the action of $L$ is uniquely defined on any polynomial function since we can recursively apply the "Leibniz-like" rule (3.) to break things down until we reach either of the base cases (1., 2.). Then using the Weierstrauss theorem on a compact set we should be able to extend the action of $L$ from polynomials to smooth functions by density.

However, it is not clear to me that the operator remains unique on the larger space of smooth functions on a compact set, nor is it clear how to make the argument work on all of $\mathbb{R}$. More importantly, it's not clear what the "meaning" of such an operator would be (in the same manner as Liebniz -> derivative).

Comment: Tad hint: Your polynomial **must** be symmetric, $p(f,g,Lf,Lg) = p(g,f,Lg,Lf)$, else condition 3 is violated. Your example doesn't qualify for that.

Comment: Neat question..